# Reverted order of tables

Tags: tables

I have the following tex file, which contains two tables

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage[a4paper,margin=1.5cm]{geometry}

\usepackage[labelfont=bf, textfont=it,
            labelsep=newline, 
            justification=centering]{caption}
\captionsetup[table]{ skip=1.4pt, labelfont=sc}
\usepackage{adjustbox}  % it load graphicx 
%\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{booktabs, longtable, ltablex, makecell, multirow}  % <---
\usepackage[referable,para]{threeparttablex}

\usepackage{pdflscape}
\usepackage{stackengine}
\usepackage{interval}
\usepackage{amsmath,ragged2e} % <-- new
\usepackage{interval,pbox}

\usepackage{pgffor}
\newcommand\Quad[1][1]{\foreach \Quaddy in {1,...,#1}{\quad}\ignorespaces}

\usepackage{siunitx}
\sisetup{group-separator={,}, 
         table-format=1.3, 
         table-space-text-post=***,
         table-number-alignment =center}
\newcommand*{\MyIndent}
{\hspace*{1.5cm}}

\usepackage{dcolumn}
\newcolumntype{d}[1]{D..{#1}}
\newcommand\mc[1]{\multicolumn{1}{c}{#1}} % handy shortcut macro

\newcommand\mytab[1]{%
   \smash[b]{\begin{tabular}[t]{@{}c@{}}#1\end{tabular}}}
\hyphenation{bur-kina}

\newcommand{\overbar}[1]{\mkern 1.5mu\overline{\mkern-1.5mu#1\mkern-1.5mu}\mkern 1.5mu}
\newcommand\vn[1]{\mathrm{#1}} 
\newcommand\AF{\overbar{\vn{AF}}}

\begin{document}

\begin{sidewaystable}
\setlength{\tabcolsep}{18pt}
\caption{Correlation Matrix}
\label{tab:corr}
\centering
\def\sym#1{\ifmmode^{#1}\else\(^{#1}\)\fi}
\begin{threeparttable}
\begin{tabular}{l*{3}{d{2.5}}}
\toprule
                &\mc{HP}                    &\mc{CAF}                   &\mc{GLOB}      \\  \midrule
HP          &\mc{1}                     &                               &                       \\ 
CAF             &0.162\sym{***}         &\mc{1}                     &                       \\
GLOB        &0.096\sym{***}         &\mc{-0.000}                &\mc{1}\\
\bottomrule 
\end{tabular}
\begin{tablenotes}
\small
      \item[]{\textit{Notes}: See Notes to Table 1. $\sym{***}$ denotes significance at 1\% level.}
      \end{tablenotes}
\end{threeparttable}
\end{sidewaystable}


\pagebreak

\setlength{\tabcolsep}{4pt}
\centering
\def\sym#1{\ifmmode^{#1}\else\(^{#1}\)\fi}
\begin{ThreePartTable}
\begin{TableNotes}[flushleft]\footnotesize
\note: Sample consists of about 100 countries over the time period 2000--2020. In columns (a) t to (c) we estimate equation (3) using a random intecept logit (RIML) estimator. Column (a) reports the estimates of a specification without controls. In columns (d) to (f) we estimate equation (5) using a random slope logit (RSML) estimator. Again, in column (d) we display the results of an estimation carried out without controls. The interclass coefficient correlation (ICC) measures the portion of variance that is due to the random components of both RIML and RSML models.  LR tests in columns (a) to (c) have the null hypothesis that a logit estimation is preferred to the RIML one, while those in columns (d) to (f) have the null hypothesis that the RIML is preferred to the RSML one. Standard errors clusterd at country level are reported in ( ). p--values are reported in [ ]. $\sym{***}$, $\sym{**}$ and $\sym{*}$ denote significance at 1\%, 5\% and 10\%, respectively.
\end{TableNotes}
%
    \begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{X *{6}{d{3.5}}}
\caption{Baseline results \label{tab:bas}}   \\
    \toprule
    &   \mc{(1)}    &   \mc{(2)}    &   \mc{(3)}    &   \mc{(4)}    &   \mc{(5)} &\mc{(6)}   \\
    \midrule
\endfirsthead
\caption[]{Baseline results \label{OLSstd} (continued)}   \\
    \toprule
    &   \mc{(1)}    &   \mc{(2)}    &   \mc{(3)}    &   \mc{(4)}    &   \mc{(5)} &\mc{(6)}     \\
    \midrule
\endhead
    \bottomrule
     \\
    \multicolumn{7}{r}{\textit{Continued on next page}}
\endfoot
    \bottomrule
    \insertTableNotes
\endlastfoot

%%% table body


AF                  &0.023\sym{***} &0.015\sym{***} &0.014\sym{***} &0.023\sym{***}&0.015\sym{***}
                        &0.015\sym{***} \\
                        &(0.002)            &(0.001)                &(0.001)                &(0.001)                &(0.001)        
                        &(0.001)\\
Glob                    &-0.009                 &-0.004                 &0.013                  &-0.000             &0.002      
                        &0.018  \\
                        &(0.012)                &(0.012)            &(0.013)                &(0.012)            &(0.012)             
                        &(0.013)  \\
AF$\times$GLOB  &                       &                       &                       &0.011\sym{***} &0.008\sym{***} 
                        &0.007\sym{***} \\
                        &                       &                       &                       &(0.002)                &(0.002)        
                        &(0.002)\\
$\AF$               &0.038\sym{***} &0.023\sym{**}  &0.031\sym{***} &0.038\sym{***} &0.023\sym{**}          
                        &0.031\sym{***} \\
                        &(0.010)                &(0.011)                &(0.011)            &(0.010)                &(0.011)            
                        &(0.011)\\
Gender                  &                       &-0.024\sym{***}&-0.019\sym{***}&                       &-0.023\sym{***} 
                        &-0.018\sym{***} \\
                        &                       &(0.003)                &(0.003)                &                       &(0.003)         
                        &(0.003)\\
Age                 &                           &-0.006\sym{***}&-0.006\sym{***}&                       &-0.006\sym{***}     
                        &-0.006\sym{***} \\
                        &                       &(0.000)            &(0.001)            &                       &(0.000)    
                        &(0.001)  \\
$\vn{Age}^2$     &                      &0.000\sym{***} &0.000\sym{***} &                       &0.000\sym{***} 
                        &0.000\sym{***} \\
                        &                       &(0.000)            &(0.000)            &                       &(0.000)            
                        &(0.000)  \\
Married                 &                       &0.066\sym{***}&0.065\sym{***}  &                       &0.066\sym{***}
                        &0.064\sym{***} \\
                        &                       &(0.004)                &(0.005)                &                       &(0.004)            
                        &(0.005)\\
Single                  &                           &0.010\sym{***} &0.007\sym{*}   &                       &0.010\sym{***} 
                        &0.008\sym{**} \\
                        &                       &(0.004)            &(0.004)            &                       &(0.004)     
                        &(0.004) \\
Children            &                       &                       &                       &                       &
                        &\\     [1ex]
\quad 1                 &                       &-0.000                 &-0.000                 &                       &-0.000         
                        &0.000  \\
                        &                       &(0.003)            &(0.004)            &                       &(0.003)      
                        &(0.004)          \\
\quad 2                 &                       &0.008\sym{**}  &0.010\sym{***} &                       &0.008\sym{**} 
                        &0.010\sym{***}\\
                        &                       &(0.004)            &(0.004)                &                       &(0.004) 
                        &(0.004)\\
\quad 3                 &                       &0.010\sym{*}   &0.011\sym{*}   &                       &0.009\sym{*} 
                        &0.010\sym{*} \\
                        &                       &(0.005)            &(0.006)            &                       &(0.005) 
                        &(0.006) \\
Unemployed      &                       &                       &                       &                       &-0.036\sym{***}
                        &-0.032\sym{***}\\
                        &                       &                       &                       &                       &(0.005)
                        &(0.005)\\
Health Status       &                       &0.094\sym{***} &0.095\sym{***} &                       &0.092\sym{***} 
                        &0.093\sym{***} \\
                        &                       &(0.003)                &(0.004)                &                       &(0.003)
                        &(0.004)\\
Education           &                       &                       &                       &                       &
                        &\\[1ex]
\quad High          &                       &0.006              &0.003                  &                        &0.005        
                        &0.003   \\
                        &                       &(0.004)                &(0.004)            &                       &(0.004) 
                        &(0.004)      \\
\quad Medium     &                      &0.006              &0.006              &                       &0.006       
                        &0.006        \\
                        &                       &(0.004)            &(0.005)            &                       &(0.004) 
                        &(0.005)         \\
Income              &                       &                       &                       &                       &       
                        &\\[1ex]
\quad Second quartile   &               &0.039\sym{***} &0.036\sym{***} &                       &0.038\sym{***}
                        &0.036\sym{***}\\
                        &                       &(0.003)                &(0.003)                &                           &(0.003)
                        &(0.003)\\
\quad Third quartile        &               &0.064\sym{***} &0.064\sym{***} &                       &0.063\sym{***}
                        &0.063\sym{***}\\
                        &                       &(0.005)                &(0.005)                &                       &(0.005)
                        &(0.005)\\
\quad Forth Quartile        &               &0.080\sym{***} &0.074\sym{***} &                       &0.079\sym{***}
&0.072\sym{***}\\
                        &                       &(0.005)                &(0.005)                &                       &(0.005)    
                        &(0.005)\\
Political Orientation       &               &                       &0.001              &                       & 
                        &0.001 \\
                        &                       &                       &(0.001)                &                       &
                        &(0.001)        \\
Trust                   &                       &                       &0.033\sym{***} &                       &
                        &0.031\sym{***} \\
                        &                       &                       &(0.003)            &                       &
                        &(0.003)\\
Religiosity         &                       &                       &-0.003\sym{***}&                       &
                        &-0.003\sym{***}\\
                        &                       &                       &(0.001)                &                       &
                        &(0.001)\\
\midrule
ICC                     &0.112              &0.113              &0.121              &                       &
&\\
LR test             &                       &                       &                       &                       &
                        &\\ 
N. of obs.              &\mc{332580}        &\mc{298519}        &\mc{209163}    &\mc{332580}        &\mc{298519}         
                        &\mc{209163}     \\
N. of countries     &\mc{103}           &\mc{102}           &\mc{97}            &\mc{103}           &\mc{102}
                        &\mc{97}\\
\end{tabularx}
\end{ThreePartTable}


\pagebreak

\end{document}
```

While I am happy with the format and appearance, I cannot really understand why the order of tables are inverted (first table 2 and then table 1). Any suggestion about how to fix this point?

Comment: Sideways table is a [p] float.  If you want them in order, put the second tabular into a float (table) as well.  Lose the \pagebreak.

Comment: I'm getting an odd dimension too big error on the tabularx which I can't get rid of.  Also, as far as I know tabularx does not support \caption (unlike longtable).  The tabularx barely fits the page and as far as I can tell the tablenotes does nothing.

Comment: @JohnKormylo thanks for your reply. I was able to fix it by using table instead of sidewaystable for the first table. Indeed when I tired to use tabularx nested in the table environment, i got the same error message you mentioned in your second comment.